# Trying to use a function in php to update a database

Tags: php, mysqli

When I write the code out without a function it works, otherwise I get a 500 connection error. Not sure what error I'm making. Here is my code:

```
$date = "2016-01-12";
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));

$sql    = 'INSERT INTO `campaigns` (campaign_id, campaign_date) VALUES (9001, "' . $date . '")';
$result = $link->query($sql);

if ($result) {
    echo "database updated";
} else {
    echo $link->error;
}

function insertIntoDB($mysqli, $date) {

    $sql    = 'INSERT INTO `campaigns` (campaign_id, campaign_date) VALUES (9001, "' . $date . '")';
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ($result) {
        echo "database updated";
    } else {
        echo $mysqli->error;
    }

}

insertIntoDB($link, $date);
```

Comment: Is this all the code? Where do you define `$link = ...;`?

Comment: Not sure but for testing use $link instead  of $mysqli

Comment: $link is working fine, not included because it doesn't seem to be relevant. Database updates when not in function, doesn't when I use a function.

Comment: @devpro, changing $mysqli in the function to $link doesn't fix things :/

Comment: Than what is it echo $mysqli->error; outside the function?

Comment: Did you check the error logs?

Comment: `$result = $link` works, right? Then you're using `function insertIntoDB($mysqli` <<< So which one is the right one here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable” and “Notice: Undefined index”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0):

The function works properly when I call it above defining it. Dunno.